# Trying to pipe stdio of forked node.js process back to cluster

Tags: node.js

I'd like to start a few workers from a cluster and have each worker pipe its output back to the boot script that starts the cluster.  Furthermore, the boot script is piping stdout to a writeStream which is also being written to by Bunyan.

This kind of works, but my child processes are still logging to stdout as opposed to the file.

```
...

var errorPipe = fs.createWriteStream(logPath, {flags: 'a'});

var log = bunyan.createLogger({
  name: 'webd',
  streams: [
    {
      level: 'info',
      stream:  errorPipe // log INFO and above to stdout
    },
    {
      level: 'error',
      stream: errorPipe // log ERROR and above to stdout
    }
  ]
});

process.__defineGetter__("stdout", function(){
  return errorPipe;
});
process.__defineGetter__("stderr", function(){
  return errorPipe;
});

// Defines what each worker needs to run
cluster.setupMaster({ exec: './index.js'}); //process.env.NODE_DIR + index

// Forks off the workers unless the server is stopping
function forkNewWorkers(callback) {
  if (!stopping) {
    for (var i = numWorkers(); i < workerCount; i++) {
      cluster.fork('prg', [], {silent: true, stdio: [null, process.stdout, process.stderr]});
    }
  }
  return callback;
}

...
```

Any idea why the above is not piping to my new stdout?
Thanks!